# Why does Minecraft crash while loading world on windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Here is the crash report:

```
[01:48:33] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Nsxjnkndijke
[01:48:36] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[01:48:37] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[01:48:44] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[01:48:44] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[01:48:44] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[01:48:44] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[01:48:45] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[01:48:47] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[01:48:52] [Realms Notification Availability checker #1/INFO]: Could not authorize you against Realms server: Invalid session id
[01:49:01] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.10.2
[01:49:01] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[01:49:06] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[01:49:07] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 93%
[01:49:07] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 12, from 10
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff907a83bdc, pid=7784, tid=7804
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [chtbrkg.dll+0x23bdc]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Nuainau\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid7784.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you go to C:\Users\Nuainau\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid7784.log and copy the relevant information from that log into a code block in your question? Just click the edit button on your question, paste it in, select it and click the icon that looks like accolades, the 5th icon from the left in the editor.

Comment: Try updating your graphics card.

Comment: Java version looks to be version 7 update 80. We're up to version 8 update 111. Update Java.

Comment: Can't. because it is too big

Comment: I did update it but it crashes before i even reach the world loading screen

Comment: if it it is a graphic card problem why did it not crash  while i played before

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by your block of error code, your Java version seems to be out of date.

```
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
```

This line indicates you have Java Version 7 update 80 installed, which is quite old. You'll want to try updating to Java Version 8 update 111, which is the most recent version.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek No, I don't see any reason to.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek The rep is not as important to me as is answering the question, if only getting rep is your game, fine, but I care about more than that.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Why exactly are you so adamant about this?